# Using the topbar to navigate from one site's meta to another site's meta

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button

Can the Stack Exchange Dropdown be adjusted so that when I am in a per site meta, for example `meta.unix.stackexchange` that I can directly select another sites meta via the dropdown?

I find that when I am looking for things in some meta-site, it is far more likely that if I select another site I want to go to meta, instead of going to the main site (which now always happens).

Currently I have to select that site X in the dropdown, wait until the page starts refreshing and then once more use the dropdown to select the now available link to  meta-X.

I know I can edit the list under "Your Communities" but I hate to have to double its length.

I much prefer to have the system know that I am in "meta" or "main" "mode" and behave accordingly when switching sites, so that going from "meta" to "meta" would be the default if selecting the site-name, and I could still go to the new "main" site by selecting the dropdown.

Other solutions, that directly allow selection of meta (and other elements like chat and blog, like the really nice proposed answer by Patrick) would work for me too.

Comment: @James can you provide a link to where "Stack Exchange MultiColider SuperDropdown" is defined? If I had not written the question myself, I would not know what the question was about after your edit. "StackExchage &darr;" at least provided a visual clue to what dropdown was meant.

Comment: Hover the new tag I added to your question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest to go from one meta to another when clicking on a site in the list from a meta site. I don't think that is what most users want to do and implementing this would be confusing for most of the users.

Instead I would like to suggest to hide the reputation once you hover over it, and show the `meta`, `chat` and `blog` button.

In this way, you have optimal control over where you want to go. It gives you the ability to go to meta directly. For others, it might just work like it always did:

[image: mockup]

(upon request a separate feature request to discuss [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256183/245360))

Comment: nice suggestion. This deserves it's own feature request.

Comment: @Tim: do you think so? It addresses OP's problem and extends it a little. I think it fits this question. If necessary, I might do a separate FR.

Comment: might get more attention as a question.

Comment: It shouldn't be implemented in this question because that would require changing the *entire* scope of this question ;)

Comment: And you should definitely make a new FR. While it answers and is loosely related to the OP's FR, in that it's about navigating with the dropdown button, it's a very good idea, and people cannot properly vote for it or discuss it as a FR when it's an answer to another question :) - Although I'd have a think first, as removing the rep "might" not be welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

> I find that when I am looking for things in some meta-site, it is far
>   more likely that if I select another site I want to go to meta,
>   instead of going to the main site

Call me speculative, but I would imagine you are a fair bit in the minority there. Most users will want to go to the main site.

This can be (loosely) backed up by the fact total users who go to a site's meta is far less than the main site has total users.
Additionally, two different site's metas have nothing in common, so it's more likely users just want to go to another site, rather than have any reason to go from one site's meta to another site's meta.

If we "changed" how it works now, there would be users *flocking* to state "*Why do you take me to Meta site from the dropdown when it's more obvious to go to the main site?*".

> If going from "meta" to "meta" would be the default, I could still go
>   to the new "main" site by selecting StackExchange ↓.

But the way it is now you can just do the reverse.
Click the main site and seconds later click that site's meta. The entire process including loading time takes about 4 seconds. Surely you're not skipping through *many* sites very frequently where a few seconds and a few clicks is a problem?

I agree that it's nice to streamline things, but at the end of the day we have to perform actions to do things, and can only streamline things to a certain degree.

### Alternative

You'd probably have more luck suggesting a different approach to your feature request. As an "addition" without changing how it works now.

i.e. like [PatrickHofman's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256181/230506)