# Show the meta, chat and blog in the top bar for other sites on hover

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, stack-exchange-button

This feature request originated from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256181/245360) (upon request).

Can we adjust the StackExchange button, aka the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™, to show the `meta`, `chat` and `blog` for the 'other' sites (not the active site) when hovering over it?

Like so:

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 3):

This is a great idea.

While a simple addition it adds really useful functionality to the navigation. And as it doesn't change or remove any current site functionality, it caters for all user's preferences.

---

*Only one suggestion:*

While we're at it, why not have "*log in / log out*" on each site on hover as well ("*maybe*" instead of blog link, as blog is not really accessed *frequently*).

- If not logged in, the "log in" link would take you straight to the
  log in page of the site you are hovering (to confirm sign in with
  Google, OpenID etc)
- If logged in, the "log out" link would simply log you out of the site
  you are hovering

A confirmation for "log out" might be prudent, but I imagine this should be relatively easy with a simple pop up(?).

Comment: I think they can add logout too if there is space. At least in the mobile UI there is plenty of space, so why replace it if you can have it all? ;)

Comment: Absolutely agreed. Just added the "maybe" in case there isn't enough space on some sites :) e.g. "Database Administrators" and "Geographic Information Systems"

Answer (score 2):

I've made a userscript for this.

It works like on the new profile pages, where you hover over a site, and the reputation is replaced with the badges you have on that site (ie. hover over a site on the dropbdown, and the links appear):

[image]

It won't work for Meta though (as seen at the bottom of the gif^^) and only works for site in the 'Your communities' section.

I've added it to the **development version** of my [SE Additional Optional Features userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features) but here's a copy you can just copy+paste if you really want to...:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Show meta, chat, blog links on hover of StackExchange button
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810
// @version      1.0
// @description  Adds buttons in the StackExchange button at the top that link to the chat, blog and meta of that site
// @author       ᔕᖺᘎᕊ (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810)
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
var blogSites = ["math", "serverfault", "english", "stats", "diy", "bicycles", "webapps", "mathematica", "christianity", "cooking", "fitness", "cstheory", "scifi", "tex", "security", "islam", "superuser", "gaming", "programmers", "gis", "apple", "photo", "dba"],
    link,
    blogLink = '//' + 'blog.stackexchange.com';
$('#your-communities-section > ul > li > a').hover(function () {
    if($(this).attr('href').substr(0, 6).indexOf('meta') == -1) {
        link = 'http://meta.'+ $(this).attr('href').substr(2, $(this).attr('href').length-1);
        if(blogSites.indexOf($(this).attr('href').split('/')[2].split('.')[0]) != -1) {
            blogLink = '//' + $(this).attr('href').split('/')[2].split('.')[0] + '.blogoverflow.com';
        }

        $(this).find('.rep-score').hide(500);
        $(this).append('<div class="related-links" style="float: right;">\
                         <a href="'+link+'">meta</a>\
                         <a href="http://chat.stackexchange.com">chat</a>\
                         <a href="'+blogLink+'">blog</a>\
                       </div>');
    }
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.rep-score').show(500);
    $(this).find('.related-links').remove();
});
```